# How to find the depth of a word in Wordnet with JWNL

Tags: root, wordnet, words

I am using JWNL library to access the Wordnet lexical database. I am trying to find the similarity between two words and for that I need to find the depth of a word from the root. I am a newbie to Wordnet and can someone please provide instructions to acquire depth of a word as mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs276a/cs276a.1032/projects/docs/jwnl/javadoc/

Hope this helps.

If you want the ready-made similarity between two words, i suggest to use `WS4j` library. Many methods are implemented in it.